# how to hide midlet icon and midlet name in j2me?

Tags: java-me, midp

I an working on one application in j2me which I want to run it as background, such that no user can know that their mobile phone is having that application which is executing in background.

How to do this? I am using j2me and Netbeans as my IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this [nokia forum](http://discussion.forum.nokia.com/forum/showthread.php?169228-How-to-hide-J2ME-application-in-background). Same related topic discussed in nokia forum.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I know about this forum.The thing i wanna know is how to hide icon also.Because by passing NULL keyword in display.setcurrent(null) able to run application in background but the icon and name is shown in the mobile.I even dont want to show the icon and name of my midlet to the mobile owner.Please help me

Comment: Hello did anyone know how to do this.Please help me i want to hide the application icon which is shown in the mobile after i install the application